# Android Kitkat openDatabase issue?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an application, where I download the sqlite db file from the server and storing the db file to the specified folder in the internal memory. Also I am able to access the database and it works fine in the previous version of Android "KITKAT 4.4.2".

I am getting the "unknown error (code 14): Could not open database" exception in "KITKAT 4.4.2". Kindly looking for the person who can help me in below mentioned points.

```
1. I am getting the error in the openDatabase() method. Why?
2. What is the problem with the "KITKAT 4.4.2"?
3. How to resolve this issue?
```

Comment: Taken ??? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: @PratikButani I have given that permission. It is working in previous version of kitkat. Only problem in kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

Android kitkat onwards the default location for databases changed to "app_databases"  from "databases", if you are hardcoding the path then you should change that, its not recomended to hard code the path of internal directories.

```
File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(name_of_database_file);
```